# How can I zip multiple uploaded files in Django and save the zip file into the database?

Tags: django, django-models

```
import zipfile
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from . models import  File


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        return render(request, 'index.html')
        

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        uploadedFiles = request.FILES.getlist('files')

        with zipfile.ZipFile('new.zip', 'w') as zip_file:
            for uploadedFile in uploadedFiles:
                file_name = uploadedFile.name
                file_data = uploadedFile.read()
                zip_file.write(file_name, file_data)

        # File.objects.create(file = zip_file)  #  How can I save the zip file in database?
        return HttpResponse('Successfull.')
```

*When I upload files occurs an error:*

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Cap.txt' **

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the error because `zip_file.write()` method expecting a file path as the first argument, not file data.

To solve this you can you can use temporary directory or BytesIO class (in-memory file-like object object). I don't know your app requirements, which approach you prefer. You need to consider the specific requirements, expected file sizes, memory limitations, performance,  disk I/O operations etc..

The following example uses the temporary directory approach.

```
import tempfile
import os
import zipfile
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.core.files import File

from .models import ZipFileModel

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        return render(request, 'index.html')
        

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_files = request.FILES.getlist('files')

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, uploaded_file.name)
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
                    for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                        file.write(chunk)

            zip_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'new.zip')
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'w') as zip_file:
                for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, uploaded_file.name)
                    zip_file.write(file_path, uploaded_file.name)

            with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as zip_file:
                # Create a ZipFileModel instance and save the zip file into the database
                zip_model = ZipFileModel()
                zip_model.file.save('new.zip', File(zip_file))
                zip_model.save()

        return HttpResponse('Successful.')
```

define ZIPModel class  in your Django `models.py` file.

```
from django.db import models

class ZipFileModel(models.Model):
# The upload_to attribute is set to 'zip_files/', which specifies the subdirectory within the media storage where the uploaded zip files will be stored.
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='zip_files/')
# return file name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

Instead of using temporary directory you can use `io.BytesIO` class. It creates an in-memory file-like object. Object is created as a BytesIO instance, which will hold the zip file data in memory. By using the BytesIO object, you can store the zip file contents in memory and directly save it into the database without the need for a temporary directory.

Here is example by using BytesIO

```
import zipfile
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from io import BytesIO

from .models import ZipFileModel

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        return render(request, 'index.html')
        
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_files = request.FILES.getlist('files')

        in_memory_zip = BytesIO()

        with zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_zip, 'w') as zip_file:
            for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
                file_name = uploaded_file.name
                file_data = uploaded_file.read()
                zip_file.writestr(file_name, file_data)

        zip_file_name = 'new.zip'
        zip_file_data = in_memory_zip.getvalue()

        zip_model = ZipFileModel()
        zip_model.file.save(zip_file_name, zip_file_data)
        zip_model.save()

        return HttpResponse('Successful.')
```

Comment: Another problem, if the file size is big enough like 2GB or more, how can I save the file?

Comment: In that case better to use temporary directory approach. You need to split the file into smaller chunks.  Loop with uploaded_file.chunks() instead of using read(). Maybe use a buffer. Consider to write another questions with example code, and post any errors or problems with settings. (if you have a lot of large files another option is using external storage services, such as Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Azure Blob Storage.)